# How do I buy Monero with my Bitcoin?

Tags: exchanges, monero

I saw a guy on CNBC talking about Monero, how do I buy with BTC?

Comment: http://monero.org/services/exchange/

Answer (score 2):

Alex, Monero is listed on all of the major exchanges (bittrex, poloniex, kraken, binance, etc.). The non-exchange options like shapeshift or changelly make it possible without doing this, as mentioned above. It's none of my business, of course, but do some research before buying into a new coin (I wouldn't take advice from CNBC although I like Monero and own a few coins). There are a lot of privacy-focused coins out there now that have a variety of pros/cons. Here is a non-exhaustive list of coins that have varying degrees of privacy built in... https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PVSBXpjHaqkJv8mLY5AEPk-6AP7BA1BgW7IOPG-h0mc

Answer (score 0):

You can use shapeshift to buy monero with bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

You can go on any exchange and do the swap.

Comment: Not all exchanges trade Monero...

Comment: Sure : go to Kraken :)